# How to import KotlinMultiplatformExtension inside buildSrc module?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-dsl, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I am developing a kotlin multiplatform project, which has a bunch of modules.

I have written an extension function which is meant to be used inside each module. The extension function extends functionality of `KotlinMultiplatformExtension` class. Now that code is repeated inside each module's **build.gradle.kts** file. So i thought it would be great to move that code to **buildSrc** moudle and reuse everywhere.

The problem is that inside **buildSrc** module `KotlinMultiplatformExtension` is not resolved.

[image: KotlinMultiplatformExtension not resolved]

My **buildSrc/build.gradle.kts**:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

If i right click `KotlinMultiplatformExtension` inside **someModule/build.gradle.kts**

it takes me to:

[image]

So I guessed that adding a dependency inside **buildSrc/build.gradle.kts** should help:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10")
}
```

But adding that results with an error:

```
* Exception is:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/gradle/BaseExtension
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractAndroidProjectHandler.configureTarget(KotlinPlugin.kt:765)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin$Companion.applyToTarget(KotlinPlugin.kt:727)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin.apply(KotlinPlugin.kt:689)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPlugin.apply(KotlinPlugin.kt:678)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:102)
```

Any ideas how to make `KotlinMultiplatformExtension` available inside **buildSrc**?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that changing

`implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10")`

into

`compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10")`

resolves problem with the exception (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/gradle/BaseExtension`)

and makes `KotlinMultiplatformExtension` available inside the **buildSrc**'s source files.

solution found here:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9209